# Print elements of the stack from top to bottom with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, data-structures, stack

I'm currently working with stack data structure in C++, and i'm trying to initialize the stack by using arrays.
Stack has a specific size and i want to print elements of the stack from **top** to **bottom**  using for loop.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Stack {
private:
    int top, size;
    T* stack = new T[size];
public:
    Stack(int size) {
        this->top = -1;
        this->size = size;
    }
    void push(int data) {
        if (top >= size - 1) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            ++top;
            stack[top] = data;
        }
    }
    void pop() {
        if (top < 0) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            --top;
        }
    }
    void print() {
        for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
            cout << stack[i] << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Stack<int> stack(20);
    stack.push(12);
    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(4);
    stack.push(7);
    stack.print();
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling i get all of my elements printed successfully, but unfortunately at the end the program throws an exception ***ntdll.pdb not loaded***.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **ntdll.pdb not loaded.** isn't an exception. That's simply telling you you don't have debugging information for some of the kernel support code. Lemme tellya, if you need to debug the OS along with your program, you've already lost.

Comment: Are you possibly only seeing this message when you run your code in a **debugger**?

Comment: What you've done is something wrong in your code that's finally detected and reported outside your code. Use the debugger's back trace to find out where you were last in your program and check the arguments used to call outside your program. Something in them is probably wrong. If not, then you've probably done something wrong earlier in the program to damage the program's state and the injury finally got caught .

Comment: Or maybe the program works perfectly and the debugger's just spitting out a diagnostic just so you'll know that there's no debugging information for ntdll just in case you needed to know it.

Comment: Unrelated: `Stack(int size)` and `int top, size;` Avoid reusing member names. Even when you get it right, the next programmer to work on your code probably won't.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, i just started to learn, i'm beginner. I tried to print those elements by using for loop, while loop, recursion, etc.. and it still don't work, but when i try the same code on the different device with different compiler it works. I guessed it has to do something with the OS. Can u give me any advice how i can fix that, if the fix even exist or isn't "crazy".. ?

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes

Comment: Read fabian's answer for the what and the how to fix. What you've run into is called [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), and like it sounds, the bahaviour of undefined behaviour is undefined. Sometime you get something that looks like it works consistently sometimes it visibly fails consistently.  Maybe the value of `size` used by the program for `new T[size];` was big enough to be useful but small enough not to result in an out of memory error. Maybe next time it won't. Maybe it always in with the g++ compiler  and never is with Visual Studio.

Comment: Maybe it works on Mondays, but not Tuesdays. Maybe it doesn't work after you play Warcraft. Maybe the result is close enough to working that you don't notice it actually failed. Maybe it makes the computer hack the Pentagon and launch a nuclear strike on Canada. The possibilities are technically unlimited.

Comment: @user4581301 Haha, you made me laugh with that nuclear strike :)

Comment: It's not all that funny, really. If one day you find a huge, intimidating man at your front door asking for Sarah Connor, it'll most likely have been caused by UB.

Comment: If you are doing this as an exercise, then put the program in a debugger and see where you are going wrong.

Also, in modern C++, there is almost no reason to call new.

If this is not an exercise, than use STL https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack.

Answer (score 1):

The order of construction is wrong. The member variables are initialized before the constructor body is entered, so `size` contains an arbitrary value at that time it's read to determine the size of the array. Furthermore you forgot to delete the array.

To fix the initialization order, initialize the array in the constructor and add a destructor. In the following code I simply use `std::unique_ptr` which automatically deletes the array contained in it.

Furthermore it's preferrable to not use the same identifier for parameters and members; a prefix usually is added to member variables to avoid this

```
#include <memory>

...

template<class T>
class Stack {
private:
    size_t m_size;
    int m_top;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> m_stack;
public:
    Stack(size_t size)
        : m_stack(new T[size]), m_size(size), m_top(-1)
    {
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Side note: no matter what order you use in the member initializer list (This bit `: m_stack(new T[size]), m_size(size), m_top(-1)`), the order the members are initialized in will always be the order the members are defined in. In this case, `m_size` comes first so even though it comes second in the member initializer list, it will be initialized before `m_stack`, the first in the list. The order can't hurt you here, but if you have one initialization depending on another member, that other member MUST be defined first.